# Jquery add Class does not add or remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Somehow the add class method does not work any ideas?

```js
$('#select-mode').click(function() {
  $('#select-mode').addClass("btn-mode-selec-color");
  $('#draw-mode').removeClass('btn-mode-selec-color');
});

$('#draw-mode').click(function() {
  $('#draw-mode').addClass('btn-mode-selec-color');
  $('#select-mode').removeClass('btn-mode-selec-color');
});
```

```css
.btn-mode-selec-color {
  background-color: #D2D2D3;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="draw-mode">Draw Mode</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="select-mode">Select Mode</button>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser console?

Comment: I do not get any errors

Comment: Your code seems to be working quite clearly in the snippet...? My guess would be that you haven't included a document.ready event handler around your code

Comment: in snippet it does add the shadow and remove

Comment: everything fine add jquery

Comment: Wonder why people are adding answers when everything is working fine.

Comment: It work like a charm bro :)

Comment: @MilanChheda Probably because you cannot earn points just by pointing out everything works as it should... Sigh*

Comment: @MilanChheda You should check the original post, the snippet was recently added and it's not the OP who added the `jquery` library

Comment: Well whoever added, it is working now. If its working, then why are others adding answers after its working.

Comment: Originally there is no jQuery library added in his code.Some-one added it by  editing the question

Comment: @MilanChheda Maybe they answered before the edit. Or just didn't notice that the post was edited

Comment: Well, I saw the answers after it was edited and that's when I commented "Wonder why people are adding answers when everything is working fine." You can check the times. It's like, free points, jump and get it without even checking or anything. StackOverflow is here to share knowledge and not just earning points.

Comment: @Olipol  check the answer below and let us know problem solved or not?

Answer (score 1):

Everything works as expect. 
I think you don't have added `jquery`

```js
$('#select-mode').click(function() {
    $('#select-mode').addClass("btn-mode-selec-color");
    $('#draw-mode').removeClass('btn-mode-selec-color');
});

$('#draw-mode').click(function() {
    $('#draw-mode').addClass('btn-mode-selec-color');
    $('#select-mode').removeClass('btn-mode-selec-color');
});
```

```css
.btn-mode-selec-color {
    background-color: #D2D2D3;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="draw-mode">Draw Mode</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="select-mode">Select Mode</button>
```

Comment: If the OP did not include jQuery in their page there would be errors. They state there aren't any.

Comment: If JQuery was missing, his code snippet would show errors, but it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

**Problem caused**:
your using Bootstrap classes for buttons `btn btn-default btn-lg`

**Solution:** Add `!important;` in your css code;

`background-color: #D2D2D3 !important;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888 !important;`